# Unable to write a Powershell function for giving folder permissions to a user

Tags: powershell

I tried writing this function but it did not work. However, when I exclude the body from the function, it does start working. I need a function which will add a user and give full permission to the folder. Any help will be appreciated.

```
function Grant-userFullRights {            
 Param(
  [string]$UserName,
  [string]$Files
)       
$Acl = Get-Acl $Files
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($UserName, "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl $Files $Acl
}

Grant-userFullRights "CHAD\sv_CS_CH", "G:\testing"
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: As suggested by Nathan I used 'Grant-userFullRights -UserName "CHAD\sv_CS_CH" -Files "G:\Testing"' instead of writing a function. But stil the work id not done. Getting the below error:
 "The script failed due to call depth overflow. The call depth reached 1001 and the maximum is 1000."

Answer (score 2):

I think you are just running the function incorrectly. Try:

```
Grant-userFullRights -UserName "CHAD\sv_CS_CH" -Files "G:\Testing"
```

Comment: Seems to be true, you were giving an array of ` "CHAD\sv_CS_CH", "G:\testing"` to your parameter $UserName

Comment: Thank you for the answer friend. But I got the below error:

"The script failed due to call depth overflow.  The call depth reached 1001 and the maximum is 1000."

Please help me resolving this.